# A question of GOMOKU

Tags: computer-science, combinations, game-theory, computational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

I am searching a article of proving that the first moving player is always a winner in Gomoku game! Please show me a article which contains a mathematical proof of surewin in Gomoku if you know!
Thank you!

Comment: The proof that there's no *second*-player win is the standard strategy-stealing argument used for Hex and similar games.  For a first-player win, apparently it's based on computer search and in the following PhD thesis: http://digitalarchive.maastrichtuniversity.nl/fedora/get/guid:36b5cf0a-cf06-4602-afdb-1af04d65c23b/ASSET1

Comment: hello! I want a proof of surewin in Gomoku. can you show me?